How to compute the primitive for $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^4-u^4}}du$?
$\int  \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^4-u^4}}du$
Hi guys, I tried to solve this integral for the last couple of hours. Can someone please help me with it?

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/

what have you tried?

To solve this integral, we can use the substitution $u = a^2 \cos^2(\theta)$, afther this substitution, is not hard from here that the integral can be reduced to:
$$
\int \frac{-2 \cos(\theta)}{\sqrt{2 - \sin^2(\theta)}} \, d\theta
$$
now make $t=sin(\theta)$, and the integral becomes
$$
\int \frac{-2dt}{\sqrt{2 -t^2}}
$$
but this is a well known integral and its value is $-2 \arcsin(\frac{t}{\sqrt2})$.
